# dynamically create borderless table with html+css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a table that i create dynamically. The table will always be at the same size, but for cleaner code i prefer not to create is statically. I know how to achieve this with static table.

I want to create a table that looks like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUaOJ.png)

I have table class, for reference I will call it tableClass.
I also have td class, named "activeCell".

What I tried to do:

- Adding id to each td, then create a custom css for each id.
- Using the ".activeCell:nth-child()" - but it sets the style for the column itself, instead of just the cell (=the td).
- applying Id to each cell and then using ".activeCell#id", but instead of id I wrote the actual id of the cell. There was no visible change.
- Using " td:nth-child()" - there was no visible change.

I am using Angular as well.
If it is more convenient or easy to achieve, I can use mat-table or bootstrap (but i don't know to style the table with those)

I would really appriciate your help.

my html code:

```
    <table class="miniGame">
    <tr>
        <td class="activeCell" *ngFor='let cell of grid | slice:0:3; let i=index' (click)='markCell(cell.id)'
            id={{cell.id}}
            [ngClass]="{inactive: !cell.isActive}">
            {{ cell.value }} A
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="activeCell" *ngFor='let cell of grid | slice:3:6; let i=index' (click)='markCell(cell.id)'
            [ngClass]="{inactive: !cell.isActive}">
            {{ cell.value }} B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="activeCell" *ngFor='let cell of grid | slice:6:9; let i=index' (click)='markCell(cell.id)'
            [ngClass]="{inactive: !cell.isActive}">
            {{ cell.value }} C </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

my css:

```
  .activeCell{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
  }
  .activeCell:hover{
    background: rgb(79, 77, 223)
  }
  .miniGame{
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: sure, I added them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:first-child` and `:last-child` are one way to do this:

```css
table{ 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

/* set borders on the table cells, not the table: */
td {border: 2px solid; width: 30px; height:30px;}

/* remove borders from top and bottom rows: */
tr:first-child  td {border-top: none}
tr:last-child  td {border-bottom: none}

/* remove borders from first and last columns: */
td:first-child  {border-left: none}
td:last-child  {border-right: none}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```